# I am getting this error (System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
Home Controller 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MenuModel ObjMenuModel = new MenuModel();
    ObjMenuModel.MainMenuModel = new List<MainMenu>();
    ObjMenuModel.MainMenuModel = GetMainMenu();
    ObjMenuModel.SubMenuModel = new List<SubMenu>();
    ObjMenuModel.SubMenuModel = GetSubMenu();

    return View(ObjMenuModel);
}

public List<MainMenu> GetMainMenu()
{
    List<MainMenu> ObjMainMenu = new List<MainMenu>();
    ObjMainMenu.Add(new MainMenu { ID = 1, MainMenuItem = "Home", MainMenuURL = "#" });
    ObjMainMenu.Add(new MainMenu { ID = 2, MainMenuItem = "System Setup", MainMenuURL = "#" });
    return ObjMainMenu;
}

public List<SubMenu> GetSubMenu()
{
    List<SubMenu> ObjSubMenu = new List<SubMenu>();
    ObjSubMenu.Add(new SubMenu { MainMenuID = 2, SubMenuItem = "Customer Information", SubMenuURL= "Employer" });
    ObjSubMenu.Add(new SubMenu { MainMenuID = 2, SubMenuItem = "Chart Of Accounts", SubMenuURL = "CompanyProfile" });
    return ObjSubMenu;
}

My Model
namespace Ron_Financial_Management_System.Models
{
    public class MenuModel
    {
        public List<MainMenu> MainMenuModel { get; set; }
        public List<SubMenu> SubMenuModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainMenu
    {
        public int ID;
        public string MainMenuItem;
        public string MainMenuURL;
    }

    public class SubMenu
    {
        public int MainMenuID;
        public string SubMenuItem;
        public string SubMenuURL;
    }
}
```

The error occurs at line

```
foreach (var MenuItem in Model.MainMenuModel)
```

in my view.

Error I am getting:

> System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

Can someone kindly guide me on what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you specified model in your view?
The `@model` directive allows you to access the `MenuModel` that the controller passed to the view by using a `Model` object that's strongly typed. 
By including a `@model` statement at the top of the view file, you can specify the type of object that the view expects.(source Microsoft docs) So `@model <namespace>MenuModel`. I guess it could be an error, because you did not include your view.

Comment: Here is my view

Comment: @model Ron_Financial_Management_System.Models.MenuModel

Comment: I add the following at the top of my view but i am still getting the same error

Comment: @Balie How is your view named? Are you sure, that you are managing right view? (You should be managing view under Views folder within Home folder, view named Index) Also, please re-edit your question and add your view code.

Comment: @Arsiwaldi, Thank you for your assistance, i am an able to add my view, if possible i can send the views over mail (Can i have your mail)

Comment: @Balie Just edit the question and insert the code from your view (if the view contains a lot of code, so insert only important parts).

Comment: @Arsiwaldi, Thank you. my problem is i get this error (I am getting this error (system.web.mvc.webviewpage<tmodel>.model.get returned null.) when i click on link example containing Employer view.

Comment: My _layout view contains vertical menu, Example (ObjSubMenu.Add(new @Arsiwaldi, SubMenu { MainMenuID = 2, SubMenuItem = "Customer Information", SubMenuURL= "Employer" });) is the menu with view i am using as an example

Comment: My _layout view is here @using (Html.BeginForm("_Layout", "Shared")) @{foreach (var MenuItem in Model.MainMenuModel) {var SubMenuItem = Model.SubMenuModel.Where(m => m.MainMenuID == MenuItem.ID);

Comment: My Emplyer view @model Ron_Financial_Management_System.Employer
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}<h4>Employer</h4>